# BigInt Subtraction

Tags: java, biginteger

I am having a problem trying to subtract with carrys in Java.

```
public BigInt add(BigInt o) {
    int carry = 0;
    int max = n.length > o.n.length ? n.length : o.n.length;
    int[] result = new int[max+1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= max; ++i) {
        int top = i < n.length ? n[i] : 0;
        int bot = i < o.n.length ? o.n[i] : 0;

        result[i] = (top + bot + carry) % 10;
        carry = (top + bot + carry) / 10;
    }

    return new BigInt(trim(result));
}

public BigInt sub(BigInt o) {
    int carry = 0;
    int max = n.length > o.n.length ? n.length : o.n.length;
    int[] result = new int[max+1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= max; ++i) {

        int top = i < n.length ? n[i] : 0;
        int bot = i < o.n.length ? o.n[i] : 0;

        carry = (top + bot + carry) / 10;
        result[i] = (10 + top - bot - carry) % 10;
    }

    return new BigInt(trim(result));
}
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong? My addition class works perfect but subtraction is giving me a weird answer. Lets say if I subtract 5943-3952 ill get 2091. When we know the answer is 1991. All my answers are only incorrect in the first 2 digits. Help!!!!

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0):

There is a lot wrong with your code, but first something that will give you the desired result:

```
public BigInt sub(BigInt o) 
{
    int carry = 0;
    int max = n.length > o.n.length ? n.length : o.n.length;
    int[] result = new int[max+1];

    for (int i = 0; i <= max; ++i) 
    {
        int top = i < n.length ? n[i] : 0;
        int bot = i < o.n.length ? o.n[i] : 0;

        int res = top - bot - carry;

        result[i] = (10 + res) % 10;
        carry = res < 0 ? 1 : 0;
    }

    return new BigInt(trim(result));
}
```

Note, however, that you don't account for the fact that the left operand could be smaller than the right, so you would get a negative result. In your representation of a BigInt as an array of "digits", there doesn't seem to be a way to represent negative values. If there is, I don't see it.

If you have negative values too, there are four scenarios:

- positive - positive: always subtract lowest value from highest (always 38 - 17 and never 17 - 38), adjust sign accordingly (e.g. 17 - 38 => 38 - 17 = 21, now adjust sign because first is smallest: result -21). Note that you need a function to compare the magnitudes (i.e. the values in the array regardless of the sign).
- positive - negative: add the magnitudes (arrays), sign is positive (e.g. 17 - (-38) = 17 + 38 = 55.
- negative - positive: add the magnitudes, sign is negative. (e.g. -17 - (+38) = -17 - 38 = -(17 + 38) = -55.
- negative - negative: as the first scenario, adjust sign accordingly.